# Angular Material Design - Bind Date object to MdDatepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, material-design

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

I learn using Material Design datepicker from official page and I would like to bind choosen data to Date object.

datepicker-overview-example.component.html:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

datepicker-overview-example.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-overview-example.component.css'],
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
        @Input() date: Date;
}
```

How can I bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning a  `value` property binding to the `input` element

```
<md-input-container>
  <input  [value]="value" mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker (selectedChanged)="selectedChanged($event)" #picker></md-datepicker>
```

Typescript:

```
value:Date =new Date();
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RMDJqr3QEeOkyf0UlMJM?p=preview)**